# Analytic solution to Elliptic PDE with constant coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I'm trying to get my feet wet with finite elements and I'm solving the following equation on the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$

$-u_{xx} - u_{yy} + au_x + bu_y + u + c = 0$

where $u = 0$ on the boundary and $a,b,c$ are constants.

However, now I want to compare my numerical solution with an analytic solution, and I'm relatively inexperienced when it comes to the analytical solutions of PDEs.

I'm looking for a push in the right direction in terms of solution technique.  Since it's a simple domain should I try separation of variables?  How do I deal with the nonhomogeneity (the constant $c$)?

Comment: Try this first with $a = b = 0$. Then the solution is expected to depend only on $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and the pde becomes an ode which may be solved in terms of Bessel functions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to obtain an exact solution is for non homogeneous equation. 
For example 
$$-u_{xx} - u_{yy} + au_x + bu_y + u +c= f(x,y)$$
Assume $u=\sin(A x)\cos(B y)$ then 
$$f(x,y)=A^2 u + B^2 u + a A \cos(A x)\cos(B y) + b B\sin(A x)\cos(B y) + u +c $$
So, solve it and you have what you need.
Similarly you can do it with $u=e^{Ax+By}$

$u= e^{x}e^{y}$
Solves 
 $$-u_{xx} - u_{yy} + u_x + u =0\quad\text{and}\quad -u_{xx} - u_{yy} + u_y + u =0$$

For a very partial test 
$u=y e^{x}$ as well as $u=x e^{y}$ solves $$-u_{xx} - u_{yy} +  u =0$$

Slightly different equation which may be suitable change to you is
 $$-u_{xx} - u_{yy} + 2 u =0$$
Its solution is $e^{x-y}$.

Comment: I'm not really seeing what I could do with this.  I don't have a non-homogenous term in mind (in fact, I though the constant $c$ made this nonhomogenous to begin with), so how do I choose $f(x,y)$?

Comment: You right that the constant will make it non homogeneous, but in order to have an easy way to have an exact solution you will have work with a non constant source. For a homogeneous exact solution, I will edit my answer soon.